# redirect to store/ market if app is not installed (Deeplinking)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, redirect

I want to implement deeplink to my apps ( Android and iOS ), I set up the schema URL and using a webpage in my server to control the redirection and also  to allow clickable link - as my example://url/page is not recognized as a link, I use normal http url control redirection to my deeplink -

I used the javascript in this page ([Example code](http://support.mobileapptracking.com/entries/25539969-How-to-Deeplink-to-Your-Mobile-App-from-Your-Website))

But some situations works and some not.

in Android , using chrome it works correctly , but using default internet browser it doesn't work proberly if app is not installed

to be more clear , if app is not installed in device the page also redirect to my deep link and I get "webpage not available"

when i press back button , it back to my page and then redirect to store correctly

how can I fix this situation ? to not allow redirection to my link if app is not installed?

hope you can help me , I have been trying for long time

thanks in advance

Comment: have you found a solution?